# Not an editor command CocInstall coc-rust-analyzer

Tags: rust, vim, neovim, rust-analyzer

Ok, so i installed coc.nvim with neobundle, by adding to my .vimrc

```
NeoBundle 'neoclide/coc.nvim'
```

after this i added

```
:CocInstall coc-rust-analyzer
```

to the same file as it mentioned in the guide.
But even after I'm sure that CocInstall command is working, I'm still facing this error:

Not an editor command :CocInstall coc-rust-analyzer

while trying to open vim.

Answer (score 0):

So firstof all i fixed

```
[coc.nvim] build/index.js not found, please compile coc.nvim
```

error which i faced before.

by changing NeoBundle install with

```
NeoBundle 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'build': {'unix': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile'},}
```

> other os will need other key for command.
> available keys: windows, cygwin, mac, unix

---

*You will see error from the topic if CocInstall does not installed correctly.*

---

Afterwards **i fixed issue by changing my config to**

```
 CocInstall 'coc-rust-analyzer'
```